# What's the technical advantage of claim/role/policy authorization as opposed to plain check of a user's ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

I used Identity Server and protected endpoints with policies and roles. Those are reflected in the access token I'm distributing to the client. Today, I got the suggestion that instead of protecting a method like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Elevated"), HttpGet("metadata")]
public IActionResult GetTenantMetadata() { ... }
```

we could skip the `role` section of the JWT and only do the following.

```
[Authorize, HttpGet("metadata")]
public IActionResult GetTenantMetadata() { ... }
```

Then, in the *Startup.cs*, we'd register a custom handler like this.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HeaderHandler>();
```

The actual security would be then performed in the handler based on the `sub` value from the token. No roles, no scopes no nothing. To me, it appears intuitively ill-advised putting a lot of responsibility on me to create the protective logic, instead of relying on IDS and people way smarter than me. All the solutions I've seen deal with security using claims and roles. So my gut feeling says it's a bad idea.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        CustomRequirement requirement)
    {
        HttpRequest request = Accessor.HttpContext.Request;
        string param = request.Headers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Key == "param1");
        string someAccess = dbContext.GetAccess(param, context.User.GetUserId());

        bool authorized = SomeEvaluation(param, someAccess);
        if (authorized) context.Succeed(requirement);
        else context.Fail();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

However, I wasn't able to motivate my choice (other than the guts and others' samples), so finally, I got unsure. I'm humble to understand that if I can't explain why, then maybe I'm wrong.

I googled *claims based security* and *roles policies security* etc. but I could come up with a name for the suggested alternative. Consequently, I haven't found any material discussing that matter.

What is such a custom authorization method called and what's the advantage/caveat of it?

Comment: `sub` is just a single claim: user's identifier. With claims authorization, you have more claims to use in order to build your policy. You can fetch the claims using user id, but that's not always possible (you may not have user info at hand or might be using a 3rd party idprovider) or feasible (high traffic). That's why you offload some of those claims to access_token (or provided to you by a trusted IdP) and not have to do DB lookup for every single request.

Comment: Using a custom `AuthorizationHandler` might be an overkill for a simple claims check. It's useful for complex requirements or if you're trying to do resource-based authorization ("can a user view _this particular record_"), other than that I'd strive to keep it simple. Auth is difficult as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still **claims authorization**, just not a good / practical one: you're only using the `sub` claim. There's no reason to throw away/not use perfectly good claims provided by a trusted identity provider.

First, letting clients send the user ID via a header is a **security risk**. How would you know if it's not tampered with, and the user is not pretending to be an admin? You can't, that's why you ask an **ID provider to authenticate the user and sign a token** for identification.

Second, cherry-picking the user ID and fetching other user claims at runtime from a database or API could work, but it may not always possible (app doesn't keep user data / delegates authentication to a 3rd party) or feasible (high traffic application, too many db lookups).

To authorize an action, you can declare policies with assertions. But for more advanced or imperative checks, you have the option to implement an `AuthorizationHandler` and imperatively allow/block an action.
It's useful for resource-based authorization, but an overkill for what would be a single line of code if the claims you need are already provided in the access token.

### Further info

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0